# VBA Excel simulate track changes with tables

Tags: excel, ms-word, tracking, vba

I would really appreciate your help on the following.
I have an excel working file with several tables in several worksheets and I have a macro that copies all the tables in a word file after the work is complete on excel.
The process is then to review the word file and track changes there, so that people can see how was before and after the review.
At this point my idea would be the following: instead of tracking changes in the word file AND also changing the excel file with the new amendments, I would like to directly press a button, activate a macro that allows the user to automatically write in red ONLY the new things he is adding now in excel and then use the macro I already had to generate the new word file, so that the new word file would have in red the things changed and it would look like track changes (except for deleted words that would not appear, but it’s fine).
This would avoid users to make twice the same changes (once in the word and once in the excel) since both files must be updated at the end.
Would you be able to help me on that macro to write in red new things ONLY after pressing a button? I already tried with Worksheet_changes (byVal target as range) but it is always active and doesn’t exactly do what I am looking for (and I cannot use track changes in excel since the file has tables and the button is greyed out)

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Please show what you have already tried (snippets of code go a long way).  However, I think the easiest solution is to turn on Track Changes and sharing in word. That'd cut out excel entirely. If this is for some kind of quality standardization (e.g. ISO9001) you can add a revision history table at the bottom of the file to track changes there. That's pretty standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply. This is what I am using now:

```
Option Explicit
Public oldValue As Variant

Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    oldValue = Target.Value

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oldColor

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> oldValue Then
            oldColor = Target.Font.ColorIndex
            Target.Characters(Len(oldValue) + 1, Len(Target) - Len(oldValue)).Font.ColorIndex = IIf(oldColor = 3, 5, 3)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

However, it is always active (and I want to activate it only after I press a button) and also when I change something in the middle of a word it only changes font colour to the righternmost letters of the same word since it only notices how many letters changed but not what and where.

Unfortunately, I cannot cut out excel completely (nor Word) since the excel file is the main official file and every change would be first made in word and then needs to be also reported in the related excel file. You should look at the word file as "presentation file" (more convienient) and excel file as the actual official file that will be stored also for future reference (that's why it must be always updated).